# google forms results - add a serial number

Tags: google-apps-script, numbers, response, google-forms

Google Forms Results:
When a form response is submitted, automatically a date/time stamp is added in the results spreadsheet.
What is the best way to also add a serial number (unique ID value) to each response so I can refer to a given response in Apps Script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apps Script to create a trigger [on form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) and that would add a unique ID in the last column.